# interpolating data: how do I interpolate data in one data set across different groups, and apply this to another data set with the same groups?

Tags: r, dplyr, interpolation, linear-regression

I have two datasets: 
First is moisture data: organized by date/site/treatment/tree, and contains percent (a moisture percentage)

I also have another data set (SCD), containing date/site/treatment/ tree and then has collection masses. 
First off the dates don't line up (Off by days). There are 8 trees per treatment and two treatments per site

I want to use the moisture data to interpolate data for each tree on the given days of sample collection(I have done this using the averages).

I wish to regress date by moisture for each given site/treatment/tree, then feed the dates from the sample collection data to obtain moisture percent.

Moisture data snip:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(17681, 17681, 
17681, 17681, 
17681, 17681, 17681, 17681, 17681, 17681, 17681, 
17681, 17681, 
17681, 17681, 17681, 17681, 17681, 17681, 17681, 
17681, 17681, 
17681, 17681, 17681, 17681, 17681, 17681, 17681, 
17681, 17681, 
17681, 17681, 17685, 17685, 17685, 17685, 17685, 
17685, 17685, 
17685, 17685, 17685, 17685, 17685, 17685, 17685, 
17685, 17685, 
17685), class = "Date"), site = structure(c(2L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 6L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 
6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 
6L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 4L), 
.Label = c("hydric", 
"Hydric", "mesic", "Mesic", "xeric", "Xeric"), class 
= "factor"), 
trt = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = 
c("c", 
"s"), class = "factor"), tree = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L), 
percent = c(55.19, 54.22, 56.8, 42.05, 45, 67.53, 50, 
41.85, 
58.39, 51.76, 38.2, 43.6, 60.27, 32.25, 42.1, 49.25, 
47.85, 
25.25, 53.1, 44.25, 46.15, 42.65, 52.18, 40.4, 37.8, 
47, 
44.25, 43.75, 31.8, 37.05, 47, 62.34, 48.55, 64.86, 
44.45, 
61.9, 47.1, 47.25, 68.05, 46.77, 59.93, 33.5, 68.11, 
52.61, 
41.05, 44.2, 63.76, 58.42, 34.8, 62.92), year = 
c(2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L)), .Names = c("date", 
"site", 
"trt", "tree", "percent", "year"), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Sample collection data:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("43333", "5/31/2018", "6/1/2018", 
"6/10/2018", 
"6/11/2018", "6/14/2018", "6/15/2018", "6/16/2018", 
"6/2/2018", 
"6/20/2018", "6/21/2018", "6/24/2018", "6/25/2018", 
"6/26/2018", 
"6/27/2018", "6/28/2018", "6/29/2018", "6/9/2018", 
"7/14/2018", 
"7/15/2018", "7/16/2018", "7/20/2018", "7/21/2018", 
"7/23/2018", 
"7/24/2018", "7/25/2018", "7/28/2018", "7/29/2018", 
"7/30/2018", 
"7/6/2018", "7/7/2018", "7/9/2018", "8/11/2018", 
"8/12/2018", 
"8/16/2018", "8/17/2018", "8/18/2018", "8/2/2018", 
"8/20/2018", 
"8/21/2018", "8/22/2018", "8/24/2018", "8/26/2018", 
"8/27/2018", 
"8/3/2018", "8/4/2018", "8/9/2018"), class = 
"factor"), Site = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Hydric", 
"Mesic", "Xeric"
), class = "factor"), treatment = structure(c(5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Ancillary", "Control", 
"Fertalized", 
"Lysim", "Snowfence"), class = "factor"), Plot = 
c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), Fill = structure(c(3L, 7L, 7L, 
3L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 
7L, 5L), .Label = c("", "Broken", "D", "F", "M", 
"reinstall", 
"S", "Sp", "SP", "VF"), class = "factor"), Mass = 
c(12.2, 7.2, 
12, 8.1, 11.4, 8.3, 12.5, 12.8, 12.6, 12.9, 7.4, 
12.6, 12.8, 
9.8, 12.8, 9.3, 8, 9.8, 11.6, 12.8, 10.4, 13.1, 10.6, 
12.9)), .Names = c("Date", 
"Site", "treatment", "Plot", "Fill", "Mass"), 
row.names = c(14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L), 
class = "data.frame")

Moisture$date<-as.Date(Moisture$date, 
format="%m/%d/%Y")
SCD$Date<-as.Date(SCD$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

So the goal, obtain moisture percent data that lines up with the SCD data set for further analysis. I want to make a regression of each individual tree and input the SCD dates/tree/site and return percent and add that as a column in SCD.

I know this is far from correct, but this is my current attempt.

```
library(dplyr)
MoistForSCD <- Moisture %>% 
group_by(site,trt,tree) %>% 
arrange(date,tree,site,trt) %>% 
mutate(Loess = predict(loess(percent ~ date, span = 
.5, data=.),SCD))
SCD$M<-MoistForSCD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

Moisture %>%
  mutate(set = 'train') %>%
  select(-year) %>%
  bind_rows(
    SCD %>%
      select(Date, Site, treatment, Plot, Mass) %>%
      rename_at(1:4, ~colnames(Moisture)[1:4]) %>%
      mutate(
        trt = trt %>% str_sub(1, 1) %>% str_to_lower(),
        set = 'test'
      )
  ) %>%
  mutate(month = date %>% month()) %>%
  group_by(tree) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(
    train = map(data, ~filter(.x, set == 'train')),
    test = map(data, ~filter(.x, set == 'test') %>% select(-percent)),
    model = map(train, ~lm(percent ~ date + trt, data = .x)),
    pred = map2(model, test, ~predict(.x, newdata = .y))
  ) %>%
  select(test, pred, tree) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  select(-set)
```

If you have more data you can also include `site` variable in the formula:

`percent ~ date + site + trt`

Comment: When I run this It doesn't return a date in the date column. So I am not as confident when I go to line up this new column of data with the SCD data set. Inevitably the goal is to compare "Mass" to the "pred" or derived moisture percentages.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Let me know if this is what you're looking for :)

Comment: So now I have a data frame with the Masses collected and the predicted moisture. the variables to organize by are: Date,Site, Treatment, and plot(or tree). the output of the above function provides the data desired, but is leaving out the tree (or plot) number. I am working on understanding the above code, and I can't seem to figure out what determins the output columns...

Comment: Another question I have is the actual lm call: 
    "model = map(train, ~lm(percent ~ date + site + trt , data = .x)) " shouldn't + tree be in here?  or is this addressed by the grouping by "tree" above that?    Thank you for all of your help with this problem.

Comment: You said you want to make a regression of each individual tree. So i grouped by `tree` and trained model for each `tree` value separately, and made predictions to corresponding test sets. So if I would add `tree` to the formula it will be just a constant.

Comment: Okay so if I understand correctly this is taking all tree "1"s and regressing them then interpolating all the "1"s moisture in SCD? I want to group by Date + Site + treatment + tree, this means there is only one moisture observation per day per tree. I want to then interpolate the percent moisture in SCD for all Dates by matching Site + treatment +tree.

Comment: I want to interpolate for each individual tree: this ggplot code should produce the groupings I'm interested in, as well as drawing the lines between. I think of it as each line on the graph I want to write a function and then use those functions to interpolate for each date/tree (Site + trt + tree = a unique tree) the percent moisture in SCD.                         
       ggplot(Moisture, aes(x = date, y = percent, 
       color= tree, fill= site, 
        shape=trt)) +
          geom_point() +
          geom_line()

Comment: So basically I just add site +trt+ tree to the group by function, and then remove trt from lm?  But I still lose the site, trt, and tree columns in the final dataset. How can I get those columns in the final data as well?

Comment: You have all columns. I just had to rename them (`rename_at(1:4, ~colnames(Moisture)[1:4])` to bind datasets.

Comment: When I dump the above function into an object It only returns pred,date,site,mass,month. How would I get trt and tree in the output as well?

Comment: `trt` variable was in the output. To get `tree` I've added `tree` variable in the second from the end `select()`. Please run eddited answer. Now you have `tree`, `pred`, `date`, `site`, `trt`, `Mass` and `month`.